# One to many relationship error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following model, but I keep getting an error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: A relationship
>   multiplici ty constraint violation occurred: An EntityReference can
>   have no more than one r elated object, but the query returned more
>   than one related object. This is a no n-recoverable error.

```
 public class Tournament
    {
        public long TournamentId { get; set; }        
        public string Title { get; set; }        
        public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }                    
    }

 public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

    }

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .WithOptional()               
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("CreatedById")); // correct column name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model fluent configuration entry is incorrect. Change it as follows

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()               
        .Map(c => c.MapKey("CreatedById")); // correct column name
```

Comment: Thanks.
It's confusing  to which WithMany() applies!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have better luck managing Foreign keys if you modify you model a bit:

```
public class Tournament
    {
        public long TournamentId { get; set; }        
        public string Title { get; set; } 
        public virtual int CreatedById {get;set;}       
        public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }                    
    }
```

and your mapping would look more like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()               
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.CreatedById); // correct column name
```

This way, when you create a new Tournament Entity you need only pass in the CreatedById and not the entire User object.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have lazy loading enabled and not specifying all the navigation properties as Overridable (C# Virtual).